# multiple query in one query where

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wrote this query for finding the highest score from 2 tables (Selected Item: `StudentId` and `Score`), and now I want to select some other data: (`StudentName`, `StudentImage`, ...) from other tables that must filter items using `StudentId`

my query returns:

```
StudentId       HighScoreUser
-1              250
-2              100
-3               90
-4               80
-5               40
```

For showing data in a grid, I need the Student Name, ... so I must use `StudentId` to find the info for the specific user:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectTopYear  
AS
    SELECT TOP 5 StudentId, ISNULL(SUM(Score),0) As HighScoreUser
FROM (SELECT StudentId, Score FROM tbl_ActPoint
      UNION ALL
      SELECT StudentId, Score FROM tbl_EvaPoint
     ) as T 
GROUP BY  StudentId ORDER BY HighScoreUser DESC
RETURN 0
```

Comment: What other table?

Comment: inner join to the table containing the student's name...

Comment: `now I want to select some other data: (StudentName, StudentImage, ...` => if these values are same for individual student_id, then use these in `group by` as well. Else decide which column value you need for each student id and perform aggregate function of these columns. In that case give some sample data with all the required column and your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE (or subquery) and `JOIN`:

```
WITH s as (
      SELECT TOP 5 StudentId, ISNULL(SUM(Score),0) As HighScoreUser
      FROM (SELECT StudentId, Score FROM tbl_ActPoint
            UNION ALL
            SELECT StudentId, Score FROM tbl_EvaPoint
           ) s
      GROUP BY  StudentId
      ORDER BY HighScoreUser DESC
     )
SELECT . . .
FROM s JOIN
     othertable ot
     ON s.StudentId = ot.StudentId;
```

Fill in the appropriate column names and table names.